# U2 Toolkit Insert function creating blank multi-values

Tags: u2, unidata, u2netdk

I'm seeing some odd behavior in the Insert function.  First, the code segment:

`AFEMItem.Insert((int)XXX_amcs.ConvData,iPos,sTemp);`

By the time this is executed, AFEMItem has several attributes defined.

```
(int)XXX_amcs.ConvData resolves to 26;
iPos is set to 1;
sTemp has a string value (e.g., 12345.P)
```

Attribute 26 of AFEMItem is blank before that Insert; after, it contains the value in sTemp followed by a Value Mark and ... well, nothing.

That has the undesirable side effect of looking like an empty value in a MV'd string.

I could add logic that says, in effect, "if the entire attribute is null then Replace, else Insert" - but that seems clunky.  Also, that's not how the INSERT functionality works in UniBasic.

Any ideas?

Note: I think I'm using a very recent version of U2 Toolkit for .NET: 1.2.0.1229

Comment: Hi Scott,

I want to make sure that you are referring U2 Toolkit for .NET’s UniDynArray Class. 
Is this right? Please do not say U2.NET. Please always refer U2 Toolkit for .NET.

Recently we have fixed UniDynArray’s Insert function in U2 Toolkit for .NET V 1.3.0  Fix Pack 1 Release. Could you please try this Release? Make sure you download U2 Toolkit for .NET V 1.3.0  Fix Pack 1 Release.

Rajan

Comment: @Scott, I just updated your post as U2.NET is an older (and deprecated) API for .NET which is different from U2 Toolkit which you will be using. As Rajan mentioned, this was a bug and has been recently fixed. Try download the latest version and let us know.

Comment: Hi Scott, 

For this fix, Rocket Track issue # is : UNDK-417 and UNDK-418. 

Rajan

Comment: I see that I'd only installed the 64-bit version of 1.3, but was using the 32-bit version in my app.  I have since installed the 32-bit, 1.3 version, and updated the Reference in my app.  However, testing shows that the extra MV mark is still being created in my record.

Comment: We have Released Fix Pack 1 of v1.3.0 (with build # 1475).
It was released after one week of v1.3.0 FCS. 
Please install Fix Pack 1. 
You can verify the build number :
1. Create LOG File. We write version # in LOG file. Send me this LOG file (u2askus@rocketsoftware.com)
2. Read C:\Program Files (x86)\Rocket Software\U2 Toolkit for .NET\U2 Database Provider\version\version.xml

Comment: Requested new download of vsn 1.3, through the web site.  Ran the install (both 32-bit and 64-bit), chose "Repair" since they're already installed.  The Details tab on the U2.Data.Client.dll still shows build 1463 (File version 1.3.0.1463).

Comment: OK, I've acquired and installed the build 1475 versions (both 32-bit and 64-bit); I removed & re-added the Reference in my project, to ensure I was using 1.3.0.1475; I repeated my test, and I'm still getting the extra, trailing MV mark.  What next?  (Also, please be a bit more specific than just 'create LOG file'.  Feel free to continue this via e-mail, if you prefer; J. Cannon in tech support has my contact info.  Thanks, Raj!

Comment: Hi Scott,

We have fixed this issue. The issue number is UNDK-447.

Please download and install U2 Toolkit for .NET V1.3.0 Hot Fix 2 and give it a try.

Regards,

Rajan Kumar